# Двумерный вектор неизвестного размера и произвольный доступ к его элементам

Tags: vector, логика, матрицы

Есть определенный участок кода, который создает двумерное поле m[x][y] и забивает его нулями:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vector_map;
vector_map.push_back(std::vector<int>() );
vector_map.resize(count_h);
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < count_h; y++)
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < count_w; x++)
    {
        vector_map[x].push_back(0);
    }
}
```

Инициализация count_w и count_h происходит в момент вызова функции, в котором данный код содержится. И...

1. Как вывести все это дело? Желательно, реализовать это с помощью таких же двух циклов, как и выше.
2. Как получить доступ к произвольному полю полученной матрице и при необходимости изменить его?

Я смог сделать забивку значениями, а так же их вывод:

```
std::vector<int> vector_map;
vector_map.resize(count_h * count_w);
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < count_h; y++)
{
    vector_map.push_back(y);
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < count_w; x++)
    {
        vector_map.push_back(x);
    }   
}
for (unsigned int y = 0; y < count_h; y++)
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < count_w; x++)
    {
        std::cout << vector_map[x*y];
    }
     std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Результат был примерно такой:

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

Но вот как получить доступ и изменить какой-либо произвольный элемент - ума не представляю. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, все оказалось куда проще.
Интерфейс:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > vct_map;
```

Реализация в функции:

```
vector<vector <int> > map(count_w, vector<int>(count_h));;
vct_map.resize(count_w * count_h);

for (int y = 0; y < count_h; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < count_w; x++)
    {   
            map[x][y] = 1;
    }
}
vct_map = map;
```

Размеры локального вектора в функции задаются заранее неизвестные значениями, передаваемые через вызов функции, обрабатывается, как мне нужно и дальше просто присваивается члену класса.
Может быть не идеальное решение, но очень короткое и понятное. Вполне решает мою задачу с доступам к произвольным данным и чтению из полученного результата.